# MySQL & Eloquent Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables:

**Users**  - id, name, email, designation, type

**Requests** - id, product, user

In ‘Request’ table field user is a foreign key from ‘Users’ table.

Now I want count of requests each user has made where users.type is 3 or 6 along with users data.

Output data should have these fields users.id, users.name, users.email, users.designation, users.type, count.

Please help me writing MYSQL query and Eloquent Query (If Possible). 
Please check [Tables Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOrMc.png) for more understanding.

Comment: Hi Coder, welcome to SO! Please do use the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page to learn how to mark up your question so the natural language is distinct from the code snippets. Also, the SO community gravely frowns upon using images instead of text snippets, so please do consider rephrasing your question without the images. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLDaniel. I will surely take care of it next time.

Comment: Do you have Eloquent models set up for these tables?

Answer (score 1):

SQL is quite simple:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, u.designation, u.type, count(r.id)
FROM users AS u
JOIN Request AS r ON r.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.type IN (3,6)
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.email, u.designation, u.type
```

To get this with Eloquent your `User` model would require a relation to `Request`. I assume `requests`:

```
$usersWithRequestCount = \App\User::withCount('requests')->whereIn('types',[3,6])->get()
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you please tell me why you are grouping with u.id, u.name, u.email, u.designation and u.type? Why not just group with u.id?

Comment: because you want all the info. If I don't add all the colums you want to group by it will not work properly and mysql should throw an error. when using aggregate functions like `count()` they only provide "new" information when using with group by. but group by requires all non aggregate fields to be provided in the group by statement

Comment: Your eloquent query is not working. I am getting this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::requests() . Actually, I have not implemented many to many relationship in models, thats why its not working probably. Please tell me eloquent query without implementing relationships. Thanks

Comment: that's what I wrote:
**I assume `requests`**

because you did not provide a relation but that is required to do it properly with laravel / eloquent. You would have to add a one-to-many relation to your user model and call it `requests` for it to work with the provided example